# submit multiple values with radio button form

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

Is this better then?

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
    <input name="size" type="radio" value="Small">Small<br>
    <input name="size" type="radio" value="Large">Large<br>
    <input name="size" type="radio" value="XXL">XXL<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="sizes" id="sizes" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="85" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Add To Cart"/></form>
```

Just a quick note that for retreiving the result I am using this code here:

```
if(isset($_POST['sizes'])){
    $myvar = $_POST['sizes'];
    echo "Your Size:", $myvar ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling the radio buttons 'form1' but you have the same name for the first hidden field.

I would suggest that the form is submitting this field and ignoring the radio buttons for this reason.

Comment: i have edited my original post could you have a look please. Thanks m8

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your revised code, surely you need:

```
$myvar = $_POST['size'];

if ($myvar) {
    echo "Size is $myvar";
}
```

'sizes' is never getting set to a 'true' value.

Note: the `if ($myvar)` works, in this instance, as effectively as the 'isset' statement but is simpler to code and read.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript & jQuery:

```
$("#form1 input[name='size']").click(function(){
    var size = $('input:radio[name=size]:checked').val();
    $("#form1 input[name='sizes']").val(size);
});
```

That should do the trick.